# How to Validate Array of object in laravel 9

Tags: laravel

I have a problem to validate data from my front end which is array of an object in laravel breeze with inertia js react combined.

i submited the data from my front end looks like bellow.
i send it as object but become array inside array.

i called them with `dd($request->merchandise);`

```
array:2 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/Merchandise/MerchandiseOutController.php:90
 0 => array:4 [▼
  "merchandise_id" => "2"
  "out_stock" => "1"
  "payment_id" => "1"
  "date" => "2023-06-20"
 ]
 1 => array:4 [▼
  "merchandise_id" => "2"
  "out_stock" => "3"
  "payment_id" => "2"
  "date" => "2023-06-20"
 ]
]
```

then i validate it with code bellow

```
    $request->validate([
        '*.out_stock' => 'required|integer',
        '*.merchandise_id' => 'required|integer',
        '*.payment_id'    => 'required|max:191',
        '*.date' => 'required|date'
    ]);
```

then the result is like bellow `console.log(props)`

```
errors: 
   merchandise.date:"The merchandise.date field is required."
   merchandise.merchandise_id:"The merchandise.merchandise_id field is required."
   merchandise.out_stock:"The merchandise.out_stock field is required."
   merchandise.payment_id:"The merchandise.payment_id field is required."
```

the validation not working properly and the array key become sparated with "." like this merchandise.date.
please give me some hint or new concept to validate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think the structure is a little wrong. Try;

```
$request->validate([
    'merchandise.*.out_stock' => 'required|integer',
    'merchandise.*.merchandise_id' => 'required|integer',
    'merchandise.*.payment_id'    => 'required|max:191',
    'merchandise.*.date' => 'required|date'
]);
```

If you want better output, you need to override the messages;

```
$request->validate([
    'merchandise.*.out_stock' => 'required|integer',
    'merchandise.*.merchandise_id' => 'required|integer',
    'merchandise.*.payment_id'    => 'required|max:191',
    'merchandise.*.date' => 'required|date'
], [
    'merchandise.*.out_stock.required' => 'Please make sure all merchandise :attribute are selected',
    'merchandise.*.out_stock.integer' => 'Please make sure all merchandise :attribute are integers',
]);
```

Comment: its work but one more problem the output become like this merchandise.0.out_stock how i call this kind of variable with "." sparated

Comment: I have altered the answer, I believe this is what you are asking to know

Comment: this is fairly simple. Just add relevant translations to validations.php file -> attributes array. E.g 'attributes' => [merchandise.*.out_stock = "Out stock"]

Comment: @RytisKli please provide me more information about this

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#specifying-custom-messages-in-language-files